# How do you run code on a specific page without missing the init hook?

Tags: pages, links

The earliest that functions such as `get_permalink` or `is_page` are available is `parse_query` (afaik). Then I thought, ok, clearly, I can't say `if( is_page('myPage') ) { add_action( 'init'... //` because `is_page` will always resolve to false.

So then I thought, well, how about wrapping `parse_query` inside `init` like so:

```php
add_action( 'init', function() {
    add_action( 'parse_query', function() use() {
        if( is_page( 'myPage' ) ) { //
    }, 10 );
}, 10 );
```

Well, that still does nothing. The code works, but hooking into `init` there doesn't really work. My goal here is to make use of **items that need to launch/are available on `init:10`.** So, I said, ok, just pass them, right?

```php
add_action( 'init', function() {
  $something_i_need_from_init_10 = //do something.
  add_action( 'parse_query', function() use( $something_i_need_from_init_10 )
  //
}
```

Which works, now, there are two cases that you'll use this for:

1. Getting something. If it's available on `init:10`, isn't it available on `parse_query` since `parse_query` come after? Sure, for most things, but remember that WP core itself gets rid of certain `get_post_*` functionality once it hits certain actions. Perhaps you have a service container that works well with WP and a service is only available on `init:10`.
2. Doing something. Perhaps something needs to fire here. If so, this still works.

But all of this is clunky to write.

Is there no way to tell WP to run code **on init, on a certain page only**? Just looking at the link won't do. There are rewrite rules, link formats and so on that one has to take care of and that probably don't load until later on.

Ultimately, it'd be nice if all I had to write was:

```php
add_action( 'init', function() {
  if( is_page( 'myPage' ) ) {
    //do stuff
  }
}
```

What can one do when trying to design this way?

---

I don't know how to figure it myself, but perhaps pipelining this process through the `page.php` / `single.php` pages will work. I assume WP has to figure out very early on what page, with what template it has to serve for any given link, for which it calls these 2 (usually).

Comment: What are you trying to do that you need to use `init`? It's hard to tell where you're going wrong without knowing what you're trying to do.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Sorry, I should've mentioned that. I initialize an object `A` on `init:10`. Problem is, this object needs to know what post it's working with at that point, not later. This object is later on used (could be on `init`, could be on `parse_query`) to output certain things to a certain page. *I might be designing wrong from the beginning here, if so, please let me know.*

Comment: If you need to know the current post before the current post exists, then yeah, it probably is designed wrong. Why does it need to know that early? You should elaborate with specific examples in your question.

Comment: @JacobPeattie You're actually right, I'm designing wrong. There's no reason for `init` to know about the post. What I should be doing is design my objects/functions such that they exist for when a post is ready to be used.